# Implementing day night functionality

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, coordinate-system, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing

I want to implement day/night functionality on world map i.e there will be
  dark layer showing countires having night now.

This world map could be creaeted through ESRI or SVG map.I want to understand what is the
  logic of showing behind implementing this.Any known algorithms/formulas.

I have posted this question in stackoverlfow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19685010/implementing-day-night-functionality-on-map).

But thought this is better forum.

Comment: So an SVG version of this? http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/sunearth.html